# AppEngine Email : Unauthorized Sender

Tags: java, email, google-app-engine

When I try to send mail I get a "Unauthorized sender" exception

javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Illegal Arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unauthorized Sender: Unauthorized sender))
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)

My code to send mail is very simple:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admingae@tecurti.com", "Adming"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("name@gmail.com", "Felipe"));
msg.setSubject("Assunto", "UTF-8");
msg.setText("texto corpo");
Transport.send(msg);
```

I´ve already give to admingae@tecurti.com "owner" permission on admin console.

[Here is my App Engine Console permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW4fb.png)

If anyone could help me I appreciated

thanks

---

Solutions
Thanks to Andrei Volgin I will register the solution

[Admin Console Correct Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk8zH.png)

Answer (score 14):

In console go to App Engine > Settings > Application Settings. Add this email address to the list of authorized senders.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer so the question does not stay open.

Comment: BTW this was not intuitive: we must first edit the settings by cliking the "Edit" button just above the "Daily spending limit" setting and then we can finally see the "Email API authorized senders" box to enter email address... This is what we call a "non user friendly" interface :-/

Answer (score 2):

Today this is little different and requires more setup for security reasons.

The zero configuration way, is sending email from an email address with this format:

```
[anything]@[project_id].appspotmail.com
```

FYI: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/mail/#who_can_send_mail